# Passing parameters to Powershell

Tags: powershell, biztalk, biztalk-deployment, btdf

I have the following PS script:

```
function Install-BizTalkApplication
{
 param(
  [Parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=$true,HelpMessage="Msi file should be existing")]
  [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_})]
  [Alias("msi")]
  [string]$MsiFile,

  [Parameter(Position=1,HelpMessage="Path wherein the resource file will be installed")]
  [Alias("path")]
  [string]$ApplicationInstallPath,

  [Parameter(Position=2,Mandatory=$true,HelpMessage="Only valid parameters are Local,Dev,Test and Prod")]
  [Alias("env")]
  [ValidateSet("Local","Dev","Prod","Test")]
  [string]$Environment,

[bool]$BTDeployMgmtDB=$true,
  [bool]$SkipUndeploy=$true
  )
```

Using the Powershell ISE I try to run the script, passing 3 parameters as follows:

```
BTDF\Sources\Deployment\BuildAndDeploy.ps1 -msi "C:\Builds\1\CIDemo2\CIDemo2 BTDF\Sources\Deployment\bin\Debug\CIDemo-1.0.0.msi" -ApplicationInstallPath "c:\program files (x86)\CIDemo" -Environment "Dev"
```

But I get the following error:

```
The string starting:
At line:1 char:1
+  <<<< 'C:\Builds\1\CIDemo2\CIDemo2 BTDF\Sources\Deployment\BuildAndDeploy.ps1 -msi "C:\Builds\1\CIDemo2\CIDemo2 BTDF\Sources\Deployment\bin\Debug\CIDemo-1.0.0.msi" -ApplicationInstallPath "c:\program files
 (x86)\CIDemo" -Environment "Dev"
is missing the terminator: '.
At line:1 char:233
```

Could anyone please explain how I should go about passing parameters that contain spaces. I've tried using single quotes but no joy.

Comment: I suspect that you are hitting a command prompt string length limit. Probably at 255 characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a space in your path - `C:\Builds\1\CIDemo2\CIDemo2 BTDF\Sources\Deployment\BuildAndDeploy.ps1`

You have to quote it.

Run it like this:

```
& 'C:\Builds\1\CIDemo2\CIDemo2 BTDF\Sources\Deployment\BuildAndDeploy.ps1' -msi "C:\Builds\1\CIDemo2\CIDemo2 BTDF\Sources\Deployment\bin\Debug\CIDemo-1.0.0.msi" -ApplicationInstallPath "c:\program files (x86)\CIDemo" -Environment "Dev"
```